# Reverse Cuthill Mckee algorithm

Tags: algorithm

How to select the start node while using the Reverse Cuthill Mckee algorithm? RCM basic idea is to choose a start node from a graph having a small degree. But if there are more than nodes having same smaller degree, how to choose from them?